# Lost information when converting from fits rec to ndaray

Tags: python, numpy, pyfits

I loaded a fits file and converted the `fitsrec` data in a numpy `ndarray`:

```
import pyfits
import os, numpy as np
dataPath ='irac1_dataset.fits'

hduTab=pyfits.open(dataPath)
data_rec = np.array(hduTab[1].data)
data=data_rec.view(np.float64).reshape(data_rec.shape + (-1,))
```

I found that in data there are some `nan` that don't exist in the rec:

```
data_rec[3664]
(2.52953742092, 3.636058484, -3.0, 1.16584000133, 0.13033115092, 0.0545114121049, 0.0977915267677, 0.0861630982921, 0.0935291710016)
data[3664]
array([  8.01676073e+230,  -1.68253090e-183,   1.10670705e-320,
        -5.38247269e-235,               nan,   3.19504591e+186,
        -6.19704421e+125,  -1.40287783e+079,   1.94744862e+094])
```

and, as you can see, the values are changed in significant way, how it is possible?

About hduTab[1].data:

```
data_rec = hduTab[1].data
>>> data_rec.dtype
dtype((numpy.record, [('entr_35_1', '>f8'), ('kurt_5_1', '>f8'), ('skew_23_1', '>f8'), ('skew_35_1', '>f8'), ('mean_23_2', '>f8'), ('mean_35_2', '>f8'), ('stdDev_23_1', '>f8'), ('stdDev_35_1', '>f8'), ('pixVal', '>f8')]))
```

is a numpy record

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `data_rec`?  Or better yet, give more information about `hduTab[1].data`.  I haven't worked with `pyfits`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Because I'm not sure why you're making these manipulations of the array type.

Comment: I have to convert the contents of the fits file (whole table) into a numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `>f8' that messing you up.

```
In [380]: dt= [('entr_35_1', '>f8'), ('kurt_5_1', '>f8'), ('skew_23_1', '>f8'), 
     ...: ('skew_35_1', '>f8'), ('mean_23_2', '>f8'), ('mean_35_2', '>f8'), ('st
     ...: dDev_23_1', '>f8'), ('stdDev_35_1', '>f8'), ('pixVal', '>f8')]

In [382]: np.dtype(dt)
Out[382]: dtype([('entr_35_1', '>f8'),....('pixVal', '>f8')])

In [383]: np.array([(2.52953742092, 3.636058484, -3.0, 1.16584000133, 0.13033115
     ...: 092, 0.0545114121049, 0.0977915267677, 0.0861630982921, 0.093529171001
     ...: 6)],dtype=dt)
Out[383]: 
array([ ( 2.52953742,  3.63605848, -3.,  1.16584,  0.13033115,  0.05451141,  0.09779153,  0.0861631,  0.09352917)], 
      dtype=[('entr_35_1', '>f8'), ('kurt_5_1', '>f8'), ('skew_23_1', '>f8'), ('skew_35_1', '>f8'), ('mean_23_2', '>f8'), ('mean_35_2', '>f8'), ('stdDev_23_1', '>f8'), ('stdDev_35_1', '>f8'), ('pixVal', '>f8')])
In [384]: x=_
```

A `float` view has the `nan` and unrecognizable values:

```
In [385]: x.view(float)
Out[385]: 
array([  8.01676073e+230,  -1.68253090e-183,   1.10670705e-320,
        -5.38247269e-235,               nan,   3.19504591e+186,
        -6.19704421e+125,  -1.40287783e+079,   1.94744862e+094])
```

But view with `>f8` matches the input:

```
In [386]: x.view('>f8')
Out[386]: 
array([ 2.52953742,  3.63605848, -3.        ,  1.16584   ,  0.13033115,
        0.05451141,  0.09779153,  0.0861631 ,  0.09352917])
```

I can then use `astype` to convert to `float`, (which evidently is `<f8`):

```
In [387]: _.astype(float)
Out[387]: 
array([ 2.52953742,  3.63605848, -3.        ,  1.16584   ,  0.13033115,
        0.05451141,  0.09779153,  0.0861631 ,  0.09352917])

In [389]: np.dtype('<f8')
Out[389]: dtype('float64')
In [390]: np.dtype('>f8')
Out[390]: dtype('>f8')
```

---

Using `astype` can be tricky, but it appears that if I keep the field layout the same I can use it directly.  So I can use it to change `'>f8' to`

```
In [407]: dt1= [('entr_35_1', '<f8'), ('kurt_5_1', '<f8'), ('skew_23_1', '<f8'),
     ...:  ('skew_35_1', '<f8'), ('mean_23_2', '<f8'), ('mean_35_2', '<f8'), ('s
     ...: tdDev_23_1', '<f8'), ('stdDev_35_1', '<f8'), ('pixVal', '<f8')]
In [408]: x.astype(dt1)
Out[408]: 
array([ ( 2.52953742,  3.63605848, -3.,  1.16584,  0.13033115,  0.05451141,  0.09779153,  0.0861631,  0.09352917)], 
      dtype=[('entr_35_1', '<f8'), ('kurt_5_1', '<f8'), ('skew_23_1', '<f8'), ('skew_35_1', '<f8'), ('mean_23_2', '<f8'), ('mean_35_2', '<f8'), ('stdDev_23_1', '<f8'), ('stdDev_35_1', '<f8'), ('pixVal', '<f8')])
```

I still need to use `view` to change the number of fields:

```
In [409]: x.astype(dt1).view(float)
Out[409]: 
array([ 2.52953742,  3.63605848, -3.        ,  1.16584   ,  0.13033115,
        0.05451141,  0.09779153,  0.0861631 ,  0.09352917])
```